# Overwrite let object?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following in my rspec:

```
context 'being an admin' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  scenario '...' do
  end

  scenario '...' do
  end
end
```

How can I overwrite a users method for a specific scenario? Say I want that for scenario number 3, user.name responds to something new.

I have tried this:

```
scenario '...' do
user.name = 'John'
end
```

But in the view it keeps showing the default user.name. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show us more about how the user is being used in the view and/or controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view may be using the persisted values of the created user. If you want to modify the `name` attribute, you probably want to also persist it to the database so that it can be picked up subsequently in the controller and/or view which most likely fetches the user from the DB.

Try persisting the updated value to the DB in your test. Something like this

```
user.update(name: 'John')
```

Comment: try `user.name = 'John' && user.save!` (use "!") - maybe your `user` is not valid and `save` returns false quietly